# Unable to Display Documents in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

while opening documents which will open in my local system after deployment in chrome browser. 
showing error:349 in chrome browser in other systems when opening the same document

the following code I am Using to display documents

**Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + filePath);
 return File(filePath, "application/pdf", originalFileName);**

Note: Documents opening in IE9 in all Scenarios